# How to unit test model method that calls method on another model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm new to testing and writing testable code, and am looking for some clarification on the correct way to handle this simple scenario. I've read other questions and answers on SO with similar titles but they do not seem to offer a clear answer to what I'm asking.

I have a controller that calls the `shipped()` method on an instance of my `Picking` class:

```
class MyController extends \BaseController {

    public function controllerMethod() {
        $picking = new Picking;
        $picking->shipped($shipmentData);
    }
}
```

The `Picking` model looks like this:

```
class Picking extends \Eloquent {

    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Order');
    }    

    public function shipped($shipmentData) {
        $this->carrier = $shipmentData['Carrier'];
        $this->service = $shipmentData['Service'];
        $this->is_shipped = true;
        $this->save();

        $this->order->pickingShipped();
    }
}
```

As you can see, this `shipped()` method saves some data, and then calls the `pickingShipped()` method, on it's related `Order`.

Now, I am trying to write a test for the `shipped()` method, and I'm not sure the appropriate way to do this. I've read about mocking, but I am confused if this is a situation where mocking is necessary. I've thought of a few possible solutions, but I'm not sure if any of them are correct.

**1) Rearrange the code so that the controller calls the `pickingShipped()` method allowing it to be removed from the `shipped()` method, simplifying the test.**

For example, the last line of the `shipped()` method would be removed, and the controller code would change to:

```
$picking = new Picking;
$picking->shipped($shipmentData);
$picking->order->pickingShipped();
```

**2) In the test, use a mock method on `order` so that the test can simply confirm that the `pickingShipped()` method gets called.**

Something along the lines of what's explained [here](https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-5-mock-methods-and-overriding-constructors/). That would mean the test could do something like this:

```
$order->expects($this->once())->method('pickingShipped')
```

However, I think that would mean that I also need to inject the order dependency rather than relying on the `order` relationship within the `shipped()` method, like this:

```
class Picking extends \Eloquent {

    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Order');
    }    

    public function shipped(Order $order, $shipmentData) {
        $this->carrier = $shipmentData['Carrier'];
        $this->service = $shipmentData['Service'];
        $this->is_shipped = true;
        $this->save();

        $order->pickingShipped();
    }
}
```

And then the code in the controller would have to look like this:

```
$picking = new Picking;
$picking->shipped($picking->order, $shipmentData);
```

This feels a little strange, but I'm really not sure what's right.

My question is, what is the proper way to write and test this code? It's easy to test the the `shipped()` method sets the appropriate data on itself, but what about that call to `pickingShipped()` at the end? This seems to make the testing more complicated. So should the code be rearranged? If so, how? Or, is this a common use-case for mocking like I outlined in the 2nd option? If so, is it correct to inject the dependency as I'm showing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP dev so this might come down to language features being a blocker.

I would suggest that the dependency injection method is better because it calls out the dependency and would allow you to separate your persistence and behavior later. For instance the `Picking` or `Picker` might be a better behavior name whilst `PickingRecord` might be nice for the data.

In any case if you can set default arguments in PHP then I like the last method you used (injection) and you could currently simplify to something like

```
   public function shipped($shipmentData, Order $order = $this->order) {
    $this->carrier = $shipmentData['Carrier'];
    $this->service = $shipmentData['Service'];
    $this->is_shipped = true;
    $this->save();

    $order->pickingShipped();
}
```

This then would allow you to ignore the `order` dependency in production code and inject a double or other type of object as an `order` in tests and simply assert that the method was called on the `order` object. Integration tests should continue to monitor that the interfaces still mesh together even though you're injecting doubles in your unit tests.

This would be how I'd attempt to do this in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! My only issue with this approach is that it we're allowing an `$order` to be passed into the method when in reality that shouldn't be allowed. The point of the method is that it has to call `pickingShipped` on the the picking's order, not just any order. That means we're only adding this parameter for testing purposes. It feels strange to change the method signature just for testing purposes. Now the method suggests it should be used for behavior that it actually should not.

Comment: Regarding default arguments, yes PHP allows you to pass them in, but they can't have a dynamic value like `$this->order`. In this case I would set the default value to `null`, and then in the beginning of the method say `if (is_null($order)) $order = $this->order;`, which will accomplish the same thing, but like I said above, this dependency injection approach still doesn't feel right to me.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that I feel good about. It seems pretty obvious now that I see it. All I did was set the `$picking->order` property to return the mocked order for the test.

```
$order = Mockery::mock(Order::class);

$picking = new Picking;
$picking->order = $order;

$order->shouldReceive('pickingShipped')
  ->with($picking)
  ->once();

$picking->shipped($shipmentData);
```

Now when the `shipped()` method calls `$this->order`, it gets the mocked `$order` object I defined, and the test works correctly.

This feels like the right solution.